# Updating realtime chat messages with MessageBus fails (C#)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I borrowed the concept of a chat app from Xamarin's sample app [Chat](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/chat/). This sample has a list of pre-populated messages which are then displayed on the chat window. I am using the same approach but have added push notifications to enable chatting between different users. When a user receives a message, the notification is received in the `AppDelegate` file.

I then have a MessageBus which publishes the new incoming message. Despite having subscribed,new incoming messages are never displayed on the chat window.

**Question**

1. Is this the best approach when working with realtime messages? Is there another way to publish the user's messages?

Below is my code:

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
       // Handle Push Notifications
            ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += (object sender, ParsePushNotificationEventArgs args) => {
                // Process Push Notification payload here.
                object value;
                args.Payload.TryGetValue("alert", out value);

                nint badgeNumber = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber;
                badgeNumber++;
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNumber;
                char[] delimiters = {':'};
                string[] words = value.ToString().Split(delimiters);
                object[] data = new object[2];
                data[0] = words[0];
                data[1] = words[1];
                //dataManager.getMessageBus().Post("message", this, data);

                //Post the messages
                mBus = dataManager.getMessageBus();

                publishMessage(words);

            };
    }

    void publishMessage(string[]message)
    {
        try{

            object[] data = new object[2];
            data[0] = message[0];
            data[1] = message[1];

            var messageEvent = new CoreMessageBusEvent ("message") {

                Sender = this,
                Data = data
            };

            mBus.Post (messageEvent);

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

**ViewController**

```
  public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{



    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        try
        {
            SetUpTableView ();
            SetUpToolbar ();

            SendButton.TouchUpInside += OnSendClicked;
            TextView.Started += OnTextViewStarted;
            TextView.Changed += OnTextChanged;
            //register for an event
            dataManager.getMessageBus().Register (MessageHandler);




        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        }
    }

     /// <summary>
    /// Gets the message handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The message handler.</value>
    public MessageBusEventHandler MessageHandler {
        get
        {

            mEvHandler = new MessageBusEventHandler () {
                EventId = kEventID,
                EventAction = MessageBusEventHandler,
            };

         return mEvHandler;
        }

    }

  /// <summary>
    /// Messages the bus event handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Sender.</param>
    /// <param name="evnt">Evnt.</param>
    public void MessageBusEventHandler (object sender, MessageBusEvent evnt)
    {
        try{

            //extract the data
            var messageSender = evnt.Data [0] as String;
            var message = evnt.Data [1] as String;
            //execute on the UI thread
            BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                //post to the output box

                if(messageSender.Trim().Equals(recipientUserID))
                {
                    var msg = new ChatMessage 
                    {
                        Type = MessageType.Incoming,
                        Text = message.Trim ()
                    };

                    messages.Add (msg);
                    tableView.InsertRows (new NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromRowSection (messages.Count - 1, 0) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
                    ScrollToBottom (true);
                }
            });

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: i haven't used MessageBus before so i may not be that helpful. Are you sure the notifications are configured accordingly for your app (in terms of generating certs and so on)?

Comment: @Alex, yes they are because when the app is minimized, the notification pops up in the notification tab and I can scroll down to view it. When I click on it however,the same message is not displayed on the chat window. So I'm definitely missing something.